# What do we call the process of cutting pencils down to expose more lead?

Tags: phrase-request

We call the following a pencil cutter.

[image: pencil cutter]

But what do we do with it? Do we *cut the pencil*? Cutting the pencil sounds odd to me, like it means actually we are cutting the pencil into pieces which is not something we do. So what do we do with it?
**EDIT**- In case anybody is in doubt what I mean to ask, here is an image of the process I want to know about.

[image]

What is this process called?

Comment: We don't call it a pencil *cutter*, we call it a pencil *sharpener* and we use it *to sharpen* the pencil.

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you. I knew neither of the terms. A [loose Google search](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=pencil+cutter+pictures&oq=pencil+cutter&gs_l=hp.3.1.0j0i22i30l9.1665.4343.1.7260.13.12.0.0.0.1.1050.9448.4-1j3j7j1.12.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.6.hp.r-qUHrgKncg&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43828540,d.bmk&fp=fd29ed2d87341e35&biw=1366&bih=664) pushed me towards taking _pencil cutter_ as the right term.

Comment: Actually my question was on the process of sharpening the pencil more than name of the device. So title should emphasise on the process.

Comment: 10 upvotes?  The wikipedia entry for pencil (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil) answers this question (albeit somewhat obliquely)

Comment: @snailplane, That is okay!

Comment: That’s pencil sharpener. When you said pencil cutter, I immediately thought of pen knife.

Comment: @Mistu4u- May I please know which part of India do you belong to? I am also an Indian and I can't imagine that somebody from India would call it a pencil-cutter instead of a sharpener. It's such a common term, I believe.

Comment: @Ramit, _Wrong Answer by a student does not necessarily mean his Teacher **taught** him wrong._ Hope you got my point. ;) I don't want to mean rude. So if you want to know, view my FB profile, I linked in my SE profile. :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We don't call it a pencil cutter, we call it a *pencil sharpener* and we use it to *sharpen* the pencil.

This, too, is a *pencil sharpener*:
[image]

This, however, is not a *pencil sharpener* but a *pencil sanding block*, used to put a finer point on the pencil:
[image]

Comment: So is a "word sanding block" used to put a finer point on an argument?

Comment: @Jim Yes, but the more usual term is *writer*.

Comment: @StoneyB- Nice :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a *pencil sharpener*, which is used to *sharpen* pencils. The black stuff in the middle of a pencil is called *graphite*.

Comment: Actually, the black stuff in the middle of a pencil is *made of* graphite, but is nonetheless usually *called* "lead".

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide a little diversity, let me mention that in some variants of English, e.g. Irish English, people often talk about *paring* the pencil, and call the device a *pencil paper*. I am not sure how widespread this is, however.

(In fact, according to this link
http://www.thejournal.ie/pencil-parer-sharener-topper-burning-question-1180841-Nov2013/
the term *pencil topper* is also popular in Ireland.)